# Is it possible to send push notification through APNS to device token generated via FCM?

Tags: android, ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

In the project , I am generating device token for both IOS and Android using FCM. And push notifications . In my research, I found push notifications can be sent with `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

But is it possible to send push notification to IOS device, By using APNS `api.sandbox.push.apple.com` to the token generated with FCM ?

Apple docs [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Api.sandbox.push.apple.com can only be used with Tokens generated by Apple. You need to fetch the Apple token in the client using didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and send it to your server.
BTW, the Firebase SDK does exactly that and fetches this token in order to send iOS notifications. For each FireBase token they fetch the relevant Apple token from the device and use it when connecting to the Apple servers.